# How can i avoid nested queries in laravel(php)?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, lumen

Here i m having two tables. I want to use optimized code to retrieve data from those tables.

**Tables:**

```
game_sessions
Id, SessionName, StartTime

games
Id, GamesSessionId, GameName
```

**Code A:**

```
$sessions = DB :: select('select Id as sessionId, SessionName from game_sessions');
foreach($sessions as $session)
{
    $games = DB :: select('select Id as GameId, GameName from games where games.GameSessionId = '.$session->sessionId);  
    $session->Games = array();
    $session->Games = $games;
}
return array('status'=>true, 'session'=>$sessions);
```

**Output: ($sessions)**

```
{
    "status": true,
    "session": 
    [
        {
            "sessionId": 1,
            "SessionName": "Regular bingo Manual",
            "Games": [
                {
                    "GameId": 1,
                    "GameName": "Game1"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "sessionId": 2,
            "SessionName": "Regular Automatic",
            "Games": [
                {
                    "GameId": 2,
                    "GameName": "Game2"
                },
                {
                    "GameId": 3,
                    "GameName": "Game1"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "sessionId": 3,
            "SessionName": "RegularDoubleAction",
            "Games": [
                {
                    "GameId": 4,
                    "GameName": "Game1"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**Code B:**

```
$sessions = DB :: select('select game_sessions.Id as sessionId, SessionName, games.Id as GameId, games.GameName from game_sessions
            join games on games.GameSessionId = game_sessions.Id');
return array('status'=>true, 'session'=>$sessions);
```

**Output: ($sessions)**

```
{
    "status": true,
    "session": 
    [
        {
            "sessionId": 1,
            "SessionName": "Regular bingo Manual",
            "GameId": 1,
            "GameName": "Game1"
        },
        {
            "sessionId": 2,
            "SessionName": "Regular Automatic",
            "GameId": 2,
            "GameName": "Game2"
        },
        {
            "sessionId": 2,
            "SessionName": "Regular Automatic",
            "GameId": 3,
            "GameName": "Game1"
        },
        {
            "sessionId": 3,
            "SessionName": "RegularDoubleAction",
            "GameId": 4,
            "GameName": "Game1"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here i m using two types of code. 
In Code A, I m using nested query but i ll get output as grouped by sessions. 
In Code B, I m not using nested query(avoided nested query by using joins) but i not getting output as grouped by sessions.

What is my need is i dont want to use nested queries, but i want my output to be grouped by sessions.
How can i achive this ?

Comment: _"I want to use optimized code to retrieve data"_ - So I'm guessing that this code does work and you just wondering if there's a better way? Then you should post it over at [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Comment: Ok. Sorry. I never know  about Code Review. I ll use that next time. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create Models with Relationships

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships

Create a `GameSession` Model that has the following relationship:

```
function games() {
    return $this->hasMany(Game::class, 'GamesSessionId', 'Id');
}
```

Create the inverse relationship on the `Game` model:

```
function session () {
    return $this->belongsTo(GameSession::class)
}
```

This will allow you to get a `GameSession` with its `Game`s

The first way is by eager loading

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

```
$gameSessionWithGames = GameSession::with('games')->find($gameSessionId);
```

This will give you the `GameSession` with all of it's `Game`s as a property of the Collection

Or directly via the relationship:

```
$gamesForSession = GameSession::find(gameSessionId)->games;
```

This will return all the `Game`s belonging to the `GameSession`

--

Both of the above will return a Collection, which you can then `map`

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-map

to get only the results you need

Or by adding a `->select('...', '..', '.')` to your query builder

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#selects

Comment: @H H approach is very fine. and i got what i wanted. :)